# Provisioning profile does not match bundle identifier : Existing IOS bundle ID starts with a numeric

Tags: codenameone

I have an IOS app on the app store that was built with XCode. Unfortunately, I used a numeric to start the 3rd component of the Bundle ID. i.e. com.company.30YayMe

Now I'm rebuilding the app in Codename One (with the intent of replacing the existing app), and the package name can't have an initial numeric (30Yayme).

When I try to send an IOS Debug Build, I get the expected error message of 'Provisioning profile does not match bundle identifier...'

Not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is using something like `com.mycompany.*` but this will have the undesireable side effect of blocking you from using things like push notification etc.

If this isn't good enough I think you'll need to file a request for enhancement as this is pretty deeply embedded into the logic of Codename One.